# macOS automator - run shell script not working

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

So I have a shell script that outputs a format of 2021-01-15 02:20:33.  It works in command line and AppleScript but doesn't work in automator.  Not sure how to troubleshoot it i've done a few searches but nothing comes up that addresses this issue of a shell script not outputting value in automator.

works in:

- terminal

[image]

- applescript
  [image]

doesn't work in automator

- As a shell script: it runs but the output is blank.  But there is an output.
  [image]
- As an Applescript on Automator - no output
  [image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please add the contents of `tm.sh` to your question. Also, why not make the `tm.sh` _executable_ and then _execute_ it directly without having to pass it to `sh`?

Comment: What is wrong with built-in `/bin/date`: `set timeStamp to do shell script "/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M:%S"`? And you don't need redundant `as string`.

Comment: it's actually pulling an embedded time stamp from a file.

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to post the actual contents of tm.sh

Comment: I'm just trying to understand if there is something I have to do to automator that I don't have to do to shell and AppleScript to get the same desired results?

Comment: Without seeing the contents of the `tm.sh` _file_ I can't say for sure, however the only thing that comes to mind is that the default `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** _action_ or a `do shell script` _command_ in a **Run AppleScript** _action_ in an **Automator** _workflow_ is  `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So if any _executable_ called in the `tm.sh` _script_ is not in that `PATH` then it will fail, although I'd expect an error message to be returned.

Comment: @user3439894 - there is no error if anything the result is there but nothing is displayed. How would you specify the script itself to maybe account for the path?

Comment: Having reread your question, sorry but the `do shell script` _command_ in **Script Editor** get's the same `PATH` as in **Automator** so it's probably not a `PATH` issue if it's working in **Script Editor**. You could add a `PATH` _statement_ to the _script_ or prepend it to `tm.sh` on the _command line_ and see if that makes any difference. That said, if that doesn't rectify the issue, then without seeing the contents of the `tm.sh` I'm done here as it a waste of time not seeing the _code_! Another thing, while you show two different **Automator** actions there are no other details about it.

Comment: You could also set **Shell: [/bin/sh]** and place the _code_ of the _shell script_ in the **Run Shell Script** _action_ instead, even if only to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was automator didn't have full disk access permissions in privacy.  After that was enabled the script worked as intended.